# Reference to enumerate item with manually set label

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, enumitem

In my document, I have made an enumerate with several items I will need to reference to. They are numbered with a simple (1), (2)... , but I need a (2') as well. To reference nicely, I was using `enumitem`, this fails upon changing one label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\arabic*)}]
    \item text1\label{itm:1}.
    \item text2\label{itm:2}.
    \item[(2')] manually different label\label{itm:2b}.
    \item text3\label{itm:3}.
\end{enumerate}
Referencing to \ref{itm:1}\ref{itm:2}\ref{itm:2b}\ref{itm:3}.

\end{document}
```

This produces, as a final line, the following:

```
Referencing to (1)(2)(2)(3).
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could define it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{#2\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\arabic*)}]
    \item text1\label{itm:1}.
    \item text2\label{itm:2}.
    \item[\mylabel{itm:2b}{(2')}] manually different label.
    \item text3\label{itm:3}.
\end{enumerate}
Referencing to \ref{itm:1}\ref{itm:2}\ref{itm:2b}\ref{itm:3}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that it does not update automatically when the label is changed inside `[ ]`.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, whatever we give inside the \mylabel command (here) is printed. Thought it was going to be a rare single case :)

Comment: You can change the command to print the label and use it inside the `[]`. `\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]{#2\def\@currentlabel{#2}\label{#1}}` and `\item[\mylabel{itm:2b}{(2')}] manually...`

Comment: @Sigur Oh! that is a better idea

Comment: @Sigur edited to incorporate your idea. Thanks.

Comment: This solution does not work correctly with `hyperref` - a link to `(2')` with still link to `(2)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post, but all of the existing answers define some new commands and then require additional massaging to get the `(2')` label to work. A better approach is to "fix" the labeling once and forall so that the referencing works as expected when the `enumerate` environment is used in the "normal" way:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item text1\label{itm:1}.
    \item text2\label{itm:2}.
    \item[(2')] manually different label\label{itm:2b}.
    \item text3\label{itm:3}.
\end{enumerate}
Referencing to \ref{itm:1}\ref{itm:2}\ref{itm:2b}\ref{itm:3}.
```

As Ambika Vanchinathano says, to do this we need to redefine the value of `\@currentlabel` whenever `\item` is given an optional argument. The following lines of code define a new item command, `\myItem`, that does exactly this (I use the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package because it gives a cleaner way of dealing with optional arguments):

```
\let\realItem\item  % save the original item command
\NewDocumentCommand\myItem{ o }{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
      {\realItem}% add an item
      {\realItem[#1]\def\@currentlabel{#1}}% add an item and update label
}
```

That is, `\myItem` uses the original `\item` command to set the label and it updates `\@currentlabel` when it is given an optional argument. In practice, we need to wrap these commands inside `\makeatletter...\makeatother` but the code above is essentially all we need.

We can tell the enumerate environment to use `\myItem` instead of `\item` using `\setlist`:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{before=\let\item\myItem}% make \item=\myItem
```

This approach will work without change if you use the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package.

Putting this all together, here is full code. I have put all of the formatting from the MWE into the `\setlist` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\realItem\item % save a copy of the original item
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand\myItem{ o }{%
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
      {\realItem}% add an item
      {\realItem[#1]\def\@currentlabel{#1}}% add an item and update label
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{enumitem}    
\setlist[enumerate]{
    before=\let\item\myItem,       % use \myItem in enumerate
    label=\textnormal{(\arabic*)}, % format the label
    widest=(2')                    % set the widest label
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{enumerate}
      \item text1\label{itm:1}.
      \item text2\label{itm:2}.
      \item[(2')] manually different label\label{itm:2b}.
      \item text3\label{itm:3}.
  \end{enumerate}
  Referencing to \ref{itm:1}\ref{itm:2}\ref{itm:2b}\ref{itm:3}.

\end{document}
```

This results in the expected output:

[image]

In practice, rather than redefining the `enumerate` environment to work like this you might want to create a new `enumerate`-like environment using the `\newlist` command from the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package.

Actually, I am a little surprised that the enumerate environments do not redefine `\@currentlabel` like this when `\item` has an optional argument...

Comment: This is a nice fix, but it does not appear to work for nested lists...

Answer (score 3):

If one is using `hyperref`, the easiest way to print the prime *and* have a link pointing to the right item is to modify slightly the solution by `Ambika Vanchinathan` by adding a dummy counter (that is, adding `\newcounter{dummy}` in the preamble and `\refstepcounter{dummy}` inside the definition of `\mylabel`).

However, personally I would rather redefine `\item` (instead of `\label`) through:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{\item[#1]\refstepcounter{dummy}\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother
```

With this definition, manual-labeled items should be introduced as

```
\myitem[(2')]\label{itm:2b}
```

That is, changes are minimal with respect to the usual way of introducing things, so that the new definition is easier to remember. I would also define a math-mode prime through

```
\newcommand*{\mprime}{\ensuremath{'}}
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{dummy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myitem[1][]{\item[#1]\refstepcounter{dummy}\def\@currentlabel{#1}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\mprime}{\ensuremath{'}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{(\arabic*)}]
    \item text1\label{itm:1}.
    \item text2\label{itm:2}.
    \myitem[(2\mprime)]\label{itm:2b} manually different label.
    \item text3\label{itm:3}.
\end{enumerate}
Referencing to \ref{itm:1}\ref{itm:2}\ref{itm:2b}\ref{itm:3}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it dynamically like this, and not have to input the "2" yourself; you just pass a suffix, such as `'`, as an argument. This solution works with and without `hyperref`, `cleveref`, and `enumitem`, basically relying on the new `\labelsuffix` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% latex.ltx
% \def\item{ 
% - sets \@noitemargtrue if no argument
% - calls \@item
% \def\@item[#1]{
% - checks \if@noitemarg
% - calls \refstepcounter only if true
% ==> \item[] does not call \refstepcounter
% \def\refstepcounter#1{\stepcounter{#1}
% - defines \@currentlabel
% \def\label#1{\@bsphack
% - uses \@currentlabel
% ==> need to set \@currentlabel manually before calling label

% cleveref.sty
% \item looks unchanged (no mention)
% \refstepcounter is changed!
% \def\refstepcounter{%
% - calls \refstepcounter@optarg or \refstepcounter@noarg
% - basically the same flow, both call the old \refstepcounter
% - same problem: call to \refstepcounter was skipped; 
% we have set \@currentlabel manually, and need to do similarly for \cref@currentlabel

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelsuffix}[2]{%
    % this is required for hyperref:
    \addtocounter{\@listctr}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{\@listctr}%

    % fix for \ref:
    \edef\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel#2}%

    % fix for \cref (if you need to, load hyperref *before* cleveref):
    % TODO: this ignores prefixes and counter aliases!
    % TODO: to fix, copy/patch additional parts from \refstepcounter@noarg (from cleveref.sty)
    \global\def\cref@currentlabel{[\@listctr][\arabic{\@listctr}][]\@currentlabel}%

    % fix without enumitem
    \expandafter\edef\csname the\@listctr\endcsname{\csname the\@listctr\endcsname#2}%

    % fix with enumitem: label\@listctr does not contain the\@listctr, but c@\@listctr directly.
    % so we patch; silently fails when enumitem is not loaded.
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/340620/
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\label@listctr\expandafter{\csname label\@listctr\endcsname}%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\c@@listctr\expandafter{\csname c@\@listctr\endcsname}%

    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
    \xpatchcmd\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
    \label@listctr\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
        {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter%
            {\expandafter%
                \c@@listctr\expandafter%
            }\expandafter%
        }\expandafter%
        {\expandafter%
            {\c@@listctr}#2%
        }{}{err}%

    \csname label\@listctr\endcsname%
    \label{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item\label{item:A}

    \item\label{item:Aa}
    \begin{enumerate}

        \item\label{item:B}

        \item[\labelsuffix{item:C}{'}]

        \item[\labelsuffix{item:D}{*}]

        \item\label{item:E}
    \end{enumerate}

    \item[\labelsuffix{item:F}{'}]

    \item\label{item:G}

    \item[\labelsuffix{item:H}{*}]

    \end{enumerate}

    items \ref{item:A}, \ref{item:Aa}, \ref{item:B}, \ref{item:C}, \ref{item:D}, \ref{item:E}, \ref{item:F}, \ref{item:G} and \ref{item:H}

    \cref{item:A,,item:Aa,,item:B,,item:C,,item:D,,item:E,,item:F,,item:G,,item:H}

    (cref does not sort items in different levels correctly -- I have filed that as a bug with the developer.)

\end{document}
```